# Mysterious brace showing up when parsing text file

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a text file that Im trying to extract data from with python. The file looks like :

```
Donald Duck, 45, 2 
Jim Jones, 55, 4
Jetson Elroy, 82, 2
```

I try to use this code.

```
with open('Exam1.txt.rtf', 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    mylist = line.strip().split(',')
```

When I execute the code and then check the value of mylist, I get

```
['Jetson Elroy', ' 85', ' 2}']
```

I'm have no idea where that brace after the 2 is coming from. How can I remove it?

Comment: Are you sure that's the total content of the file? In particular, are you sure it isn't an RTF file? RTF files have markup in addition to the content that you word processor might display.

Comment: Is the file an `rtf` actually? They are not plain text...

Comment: Yea i think it is... when I tried to save it as a .txt it said I could not do that and had to make it 'exam1.txt.rtf'. Do you guys know how I can make it just a txt file? im using textedit on a mac pro.

Comment: In textedit, go to `Format` up the top and choose `Make Plain Text`.

Comment: Ah perfect.... Thanks a lot grc .. I looked for a good 15 min on a couple forums and it seemed like everyone thought youd have to download a new text editor or something...works perfect tho thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we said in the comments, .rtf files are not plain text files, so when you open one with `open()` in python, you're going to read in all of the other stuff that .rtf files use for formatting- including `}`s.